# How do I properly define an empty string in haskell?

Tags: string, list, function, haskell, functional-programming

I'm having a problem with my program and I was able to isolate the problem. I managed to reduce it to this simpler problem. Lets say I have the function

```
fn:: String -> String
fn (x:xs)
    | null (x:xs) = "empty"
    | otherwise = "hello"
```

Typing in random stuff returns `"hello"` but if I do,

```
fn ""
```

I get the non-exhaustive pattern error. Since "" is suppose to be an empty list, `[]`, shouldn't it match to my first pattern and return `"empty"`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `String` in Haskell is a list of characters. So to match the empty `String` you need to match an empty list (`[]`). Your pattern `(x:xs)` will only match lists or `String`s with at least one element because it consists of one element (`x`) and the rest (`xs`), which could be empty or non-empty.

A working version of your function would look like this:

```
fn :: String -> String
fn [] = "empty"
fn (x:xs) = "hello"
```

This will return `"empty"` for `fn ""`.

Comment: Thanks alot, I should of seen that!

Comment: Of course, the empty _string literal_ `""` can also be used in patterns, this function could be written `fn "" = "empty"; fn _  = "hello"`.

Answer (score 9):

Your function

```
fn:: String -> String
fn (x:xs)
    | null (x:xs) = "empty"
    | otherwise = "hello"
```

would be better written as:

```
fn :: String -> String
fn x | null x    = "empty"
     | otherwise = "hello"
```

or

```
fn :: String -> String
fn "" = "empty"
fn _  = "hello"
```

Since `null (x:xs)` is certainly wrong (always False).

I prefer the latter, since it makes clear you care only for String types.

This is a slightly weird function though. I haven't seen it in practice.